# Proving $x^{\log n} = n^{\log x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-functions

How could one go about proving that $$x^{\log n} = n^{\log x}\ {?}$$ I'm not really sure how to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, $$x^{\log(n)}=n^{\log (x)}$$
Taking log on base $x$, we get

$$\log_x(x^{\log(n)})=\log_x(n^{\log (x)})$$
$$\log(n)\log_x(x)=\log (x)\log_x(n)$$
$$\log(n)=\log (x)\log_x(n)$$
$$\frac{\log(n)}{\log (x)}=\log_x(n)$$
$$\log_x(n)=\log_x(n)$$
Hence, proved

Answer (score 5):

You can begin with
$$(\log N)(\log x)=(\log x)(\log N)$$
Then 
\begin{align}
e^{(\log N)(\log x)}&=e^{(\log x)(\log N)}\\
(e^{\log N})^{\log x}&=(e^{\log x})^{\log N}\\
N^{\log x}&=x^{\log N}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$
x^{\log(N)} = \left( 10^{\log(x)} \right)^{\log(N)} = 
10^{\log(x)\log(N)}
$$
Alternatively, try taking the log of both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\log_an=N,\log_ax=X\implies n=a^N,x=a^X$

$x^{\log n}=(a^X)^N=a^{XN}$

$n^{\log_ax}=?$